# How do I toggle printing to STDOUT/STDERR dynamically in Perl?

Tags: perl

I'm curious if I can toggle between printing to STDOUT or STDERR based on some value or inline expression (without using an if statement).

```
print ($someFlag ? STDOUT : STDERR) "hello world!"
```

Obviously, that syntax doesn't work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think this will do what you want:

```
print {$someFlag ? *STDOUT : *STDERR} "hello world!";
```

A similar example can be seen in the documentation for [print](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html). Use [typeglobs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Typeglobs-and-Filehandles) so that it will run under `use strict`.

Another strategy is to define your own printing function that will behave differently, depending on the value of `$someFlag`.

Answer (score 6):

Do you need to evaluate for each call to `print`?

If not, would this work for you:

```
my $redir = $someFlag ? STDOUT : STDERR;
print $redir "hello world!\n";
```

Comment: I'll take it. I only have one call to print, but 2 lines to do it are fine. Just thought it would be nice inline ...

Answer (score 4):

One mechanism is to 'select' the output descriptor (file channel).

```
select STDERR;
print ...goes to STDERR...;
select STDOUT;
print ...goes to STDOUT...;
```

<s>I suspect this is now deprecated, though.</s>

Comment: @ysth Why would you deprecate it?  Because its global side effect that makes the convenient shorthand of "print $string == print STDOUT $string" unreliable.  And it overloads the select() function with two totally different meanings.

Answer (score 3):

I wrap this sort of thing in a method that returns the appropriate filehandle:

```
 print { $obj->which_handle_do_I_want } "Some message";
```

You might want to look at how [IO::Interactive](http://search.cpan.org/dist/IO-Interactive).

However, if you're doing this for logging, I recommend [Log::Log4perl](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Log-Log4perl) since you can not only change where the output goes, but can send the output to multiple places, set priorities for the message, and a lot more. And, you can change all of that without changing the source.